# Several selects - reset remaining selects when option in one select is selected

Tags: jquery, select

I have a page with multiple select boxes. I would like to be able to reset the other selects to their default state when an option has been selected in one of the select boxes.
I have made an example here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkV2/).

But how do I catch the selected option and its parent selectbox?

I have tried with something like:

```
<div class="selects">
<select>
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="selects">
<select>
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="selects">
<select>
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And:

```
$('.selects option[selected="selected"]').each(
    function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('selected');
    }
);
$('.selects select').change(function() {
    $(this, "option:first").attr('selected','selected');
});
```

The default state is always the first option in each select box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset the other selects, you need to exclude the current from the selector and set the `val()` back to the default. Try this:

```
$('.selects select').change(function() {
    $('.selects select').not(this).val('');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkV2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write the javascript part ..

```
$('.selects option[selected]').removeAttr('selected');
$('.selects select').change(function(e) {
    // relative lookup
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('select').each(function(e,i){
        $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('.selects select').change(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").prevAll().each(function() {
        $(this).find("select option:first").prop("selected", true);
    })
});
```

This sets all parent select elements to their default values.